# Flutter API keep loading and not showing

Tags: android, flutter, api, rest, dart

So i tried to create a listview of a news with this API https://newsapi.org/s/us-news-api but when i tried to implement it in my App it keeps loading and never show the data.

here is my homepage code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/NewsArticle/components/list_tile.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/NewsArticle/models/article_models.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/NewsArticle/services/api_service.dart';

class NewsHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  //const NewsHomePage({super.key});

  ApiService client = ApiService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Get.isDarkMode?Colors.grey[600]:Colors.white,
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: ()=>Get.back(),
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios,
          color: Get.isDarkMode?Colors.white:Colors.grey
          ),
        ),
        title:  Text("News & Article", style: TextStyle(
          color: Get.isDarkMode?Colors.white:Colors.black
        ),),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: client.getArticle(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Article>> snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.hasData){
            List<Article>? articles = snapshot.data;
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: articles!.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => listTile(articles[index])
            );
          }
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

my API Service

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/NewsArticle/models/article_models.dart';

class ApiService {




  final endPointUrl = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=cacee27fff544eb39d5fb29b28ca3788"; 


   Future<List<Article>> getArticle() async{
    Response res = await get(Uri.parse(endPointUrl));

    if(res.statusCode==200){
      Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(res.body);

      List<dynamic> body = json['articles'];

      List<Article> articles = body.map((dynamic item) => Article.fromJson(item)).toList();
      return articles;
    }else{

      throw("Cant get the News");
    }

  }
}
```

here is my model class

```
import 'source_models.dart';

class Article{
  Source source;
  String author;
  String title;
  String description;
  String url;
  String urlToImage;
  String publishedAt;
  String content;

  Article({
    required this.source,
    required this.author,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.url,
    required this.urlToImage,
    required this.publishedAt,
    required this.content
  });

  factory Article.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return Article(
      source: Source.fromJson(json['source']), 
      author: json['author'] as String, 
      title: json['title'] as String, 
      description: json['description'] as String, 
      url: json['url'] as String, 
      urlToImage: json['urlToImage'] as String, 
      publishedAt: json['publishedAt'] as String, 
      content: json['content'] as String
    );
  }
}
```

Adding my customtile code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/NewsArticle/models/article_models.dart';

Widget listTile(Article article){
  return Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(12),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Get.isDarkMode?Colors.white:Colors.black,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Get.isDarkMode?Colors.white:Colors.black,
          blurRadius: 3
        )
      ]
    ),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage(article.urlToImage)
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),

          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 9),
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.red,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
          ),
          child: Text(article.source.name),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 8,),
        Text(article.title, style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 16,
        ),)
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

i dont know how this happening but i followed everysecond in a yt tutorial but still got this never stop loading. let me know if you guys needs to see my other codes if necessary. thankyou guys

Comment: please can you check you are getting data properly in you model class variable and articles returning its properly?

Comment: hellos sir, i have added my model class in my question. thankyou

Comment: First of all check that, are you getting response, print your response in console?. and if yes, once you get response, are you updating states ?

Comment: i have tried that, and didnt get the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I check your code, you have to update your Article class. Because some values are null in API response, so that causes issue. To handle that You have to generate dart model class for APIs response by using [json to dart](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) convertor.

Here is updated class:

```
class Articles {
  List<Articles>? articles;

  Articles({this.articles});

  Articles.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['articles'] != null) {
      articles = <Articles>[];
      json['articles'].forEach((v) {
        articles!.add(Articles.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (articles != null) {
      data['articles'] = articles!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Article {
  Source? source;
  String? author;
  String? title;
  String? description;
  String? url;
  String? urlToImage;
  String? publishedAt;
  String? content;

  Article(
      {source,
      author,
      title,
      description,
      url,
      urlToImage,
      publishedAt,
      content});

  Article.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    source = json['source'] != null ? Source.fromJson(json['source']) : null;
    author = json['author'];
    title = json['title'];
    description = json['description'];
    url = json['url'];
    urlToImage = json['urlToImage'];
    publishedAt = json['publishedAt'];
    content = json['content'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (source != null) {
      data['source'] = source!.toJson();
    }
    data['author'] = author;
    data['title'] = title;
    data['description'] = description;
    data['url'] = url;
    data['urlToImage'] = urlToImage;
    data['publishedAt'] = publishedAt;
    data['content'] = content;
    return data;
  }
}

class Source {
  String? id;
  String? name;

  Source({id, name});

  Source.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['id'] = id;
    data['name'] = name;
    return data;
  }
}
```

and listTile widget will be :

```
 Widget listTile(Article article) {
  return Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(12),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.black,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
        boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.black, blurRadius: 3)]),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage(article.urlToImage!)),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 9),
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.red,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
          ),
          child: Text(article.source!.name!),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 8,
        ),
        Text(
          article.title!,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 16,
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: using ur code, i cant call the title, source and urlToImage in my custom tile class. im able to fix the error by creating a getter, but when i run it, it shows a stack overflow error. how do i fix this sir? thankyou

Comment: Can you please add code of your custom class. So I can help further

Comment: hello sir, i've added my customtile class got a red underline in "urlToImage, source, and title" thankyou

Comment: In ListTile widget replace it to "Articles" not just "Article" -> Widget listTile(Articles article)" also as you have some null values you have to handle null values in ListTile widget.  I have also updated code in my answer

Comment: im sorry to keep bothering u sir, bu i got another error in "itemBuilder: (context, index) => listTile(articles[index])" on my HomePage code, it has red underline in ```articles[index]``` . the error says "The argument type 'Article' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Articles'." how can i fix it? thankyou

Comment: Change it to "listTile(articles[index].articles![index])" and it will work. but you have to handle null values.

Comment: yeah it says "Null check operator used on a null value" when i run the app, where can i handle the null values?

Comment: I have update my answer, Please check it

Comment: its seems to start working sir as it shows one news tile in my NewsHomePage, but below the one news tile there is still a red error saying "Null check operator used on a null value" and i also remove the ```.articles![index]``` in ```listTile(articles[index].articles![index])``` cause there is a red underline in it, im still confused and dont know whats going on

Comment: hello sir, i have opened another question regarding this issue, but i will still accept your answer as the right one, feel free to check my other question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74957550/flutter-null-check-operator-used-on-a-null-value-error so you might get 2 accepted answers for my problem :) thankyou so much sir

Answer (score 0):

I run this API in postman and get response in html format. There in response they mentioned to get reponse by this API
**`https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=gb&apiKey=API_KEY`**

Try this one, Maybe it works.

Comment: still the same sir, doesnt work

Comment: Do you have a valid API key? What response do you get this time? Try on Postman first then implement in app.