# Flutter "Null check operator used on a null value" error

Tags: android, flutter, rest, dart, dart-null-safety

i was trying to create a news app with news api, but i got a weird error when 1 tile of the news actually showedup but there's also an error message in the app.

[image: Like this]

i need help with how do i get rid of this error.

so below here is the codes for my app

here is my homepage code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/NewsArticle/components/list_tile.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/NewsArticle/models/article_models.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/NewsArticle/services/api_service.dart';

class NewsHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  //const NewsHomePage({super.key});

  ApiService client = ApiService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Get.isDarkMode?Colors.grey[600]:Colors.white,
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: ()=>Get.back(),
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios,
          color: Get.isDarkMode?Colors.white:Colors.grey
          ),
        ),
        title:  Text("News & Article", style: TextStyle(
          color: Get.isDarkMode?Colors.white:Colors.black
        ),),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: client.getArticle(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Article>> snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.hasData){
            List<Article>? articles = snapshot.data;
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: articles!.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => listTile(articles[index])
            );
          }
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My APIService class

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/NewsArticle/models/article_models.dart';

class ApiService {

  final endPointUrl = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=gb&apiKey=cacee27fff544eb39d5fb29b28ca3788"; 

   Future<List<Article>> getArticle() async{
    Response res = await get(Uri.parse(endPointUrl));

    if(res.statusCode==200){
      Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(res.body);

      List<dynamic> body = json['articles'];

      List<Article> articles = body.map((dynamic item) => Article.fromJson(item)).toList();
      return articles;
    }else{

      throw("Cant get the News");
    }

  }
}
```

my News/Article model class

```
import 'source_models.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/NewsArticle/components/list_tile.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/NewsArticle/models/source_models.dart';

class Articles {
  List<Articles>? articles;

  Articles({this.articles});

  Articles.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['articles'] != null) {
      articles = <Articles>[];
      json['articles'].forEach((v) {
        articles!.add(Articles.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (articles != null) {
      data['articles'] = articles!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Article {
  Source? source;
  String? author;
  String? title;
  String? description;
  String? url;
  String? urlToImage;
  String? publishedAt;
  String? content;

  Article(
      {source,
      author,
      title,
      description,
      url,
      urlToImage,
      publishedAt,
      content});

  Article.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    source = json['source'] != null ? Source.fromJson(json['source']) : null;
    author = json['author'];
    title = json['title'];
    description = json['description'];
    url = json['url'];
    urlToImage = json['urlToImage'];
    publishedAt = json['publishedAt'];
    content = json['content'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (source != null) {
      data['source'] = source!.toJson();
    }
    data['author'] = author;
    data['title'] = title;
    data['description'] = description;
    data['url'] = url;
    data['urlToImage'] = urlToImage;
    data['publishedAt'] = publishedAt;
    data['content'] = content;
    return data;
  }
}

class Source {
  String? id;
  String? name;

  Source({id, name});

  Source.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['id'] = id;
    data['name'] = name;
    return data;
  }
}
```

and lastly my custometile class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/NewsArticle/models/article_models.dart';

 Widget listTile(Article article) {
  return Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(12),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.black,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
        boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.black, blurRadius: 3)]),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage(article.urlToImage!)),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 9),
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.red,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
          ),
          child: Text(article.source!.name!),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 8,
        ),
        Text(
          article.title!,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 16,
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

let me know if you guys needs to see the other codes if neccesary. thankyou so much guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### add FutureBuilder return Type and check it!

```
 body: FutureBuilder<List<Article>>(
        future: client.getArticle(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Article>> snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.hasData&&snapshot.data!=null&& snapshot.data!.isNotEmpty){
            List<Article>? articles = snapshot.data;
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: articles!.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => listTile(articles[index])
            );
          }
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
        },
      ),
    );
```

Comment: its seems to be working, but when i scroll down for like 8 tiles, it shows the error again sir, are there any ways i can fix this? thankyou

Comment: ListView.builder add   "shrinkWrap: true"

Answer (score 1):

it is because you have used ! null check operator which is causing error when the value is null try replacing this operator by this ? operator like this.

change this line

`itemCount: articles!.length,`

to this

```
itemCount: articles?.length,
```

Answer (score 1):

In API response some of response data has null value : `article.urlImage` is null, which cause this issue. To handle it either you have to provide  different container style or default image.

Code as below: In `listTile` for different container style

```
article.urlToImage != null
            ? Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image:
                      DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage(article.urlToImage!)),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                ),
              )
            : Container(),
```

OR In `listTile` for default image :

```
Container(
     decoration: BoxDecoration(
         image: DecorationImage(
            image: NetworkImage(article.urlToImage != null
                  ? article.urlToImage!
                  : "Your defualt image here")),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                ),
              )
```